# rails + simpleform: selected does not set to be enum's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, simple-form

I have a enum definition for my User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum program_of_study: [
    :program_of_study_unknown, :program_of_study_cs, :program_of_study_ceg,
    :program_of_study_is, :program_of_study_science,
    :program_of_study_engineering, :program_of_study_fass,
    :program_of_study_business, :program_of_study_others
  ]
end
```

And in simple_form I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(locals[:user], wrapper: :horizontal_form, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'},
                    url: {action: (locals[:is_new] ? 'create' : 'update')}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :program_of_study, collection: User.program_of_studies, include_blank: false, selected: locals[:user].program_of_study %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

However, it seems that although the `program_of_study` of a user is `'program_of_study_science'`(by checking in rails console), when I render the form, the shown select element still has `'program_of_study_unknown'` as the displayed one. The correct one was not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end

```
<%= f.input :program_of_study, collection: User.program_of_studies, include_blank: false, selected: User.program_of_studies[locals[:user].program_of_study] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the enum I used the keys and it seems to work, have you tried that:

```
collection: User.program_of_studies.keys
```

I didn't have to specify a `selected` option. My code looks like this:

```
input :status, as: :select, collection: Venue.statuses.keys, include_blank: false
```

Comment: So if I did not get it wrongly, the posted "value" will be something like "program_of_study_cs"?

Comment: Yes and the way enum works, that valid should work. Have you tried it?